# Streamreader not reading all lines

Tags: vb.net, hash, project, streamreader

I am working on a little tool that allows the selection of a single file. Where it will calculate the `SHA2 hash` and shows it in a simple GUI then takes the value and checks if that hash is listed in a blacklist text file. If it is listed then it will flag it as dirty, and if not it will pass it as clean.

But after hitting Google for hours on end and sifting through many online sources I decided let's just ask for advise and help.

That said while my program does work I seem to run into a problem, since no matter what I do ,it only reads the first line of my "*blacklist*" and refuses to read the whole list or to actually go line by line to see if there is a match.
No matter if I got 100 or 1 `SHA2 hash` in it.

So example if I were to have 5 files which I add to the so called *blacklist*.  By pre-calculating their `SHA2 value`. Then no matter what my little tool will only flag one file which is blacklisted as a match.

Yet the moment I use the `reset` button and I select a different (also blacklisted) file, it passes it as clean while its not. As far as I can tell it is always the first `SHA2 hash` it seems to flag and ignoring the others. I personally think the program does not even check beyond the first hash.

Now the blacklist file is made up very simple.
*example:

```
1afde1cbccd2ab36f90973cb985072a01ebdc64d8fdba6a895c855d90f925043
2afde1cbccd2ab36f90973cb985072a01ebdc64d8fdba6a895c855d90f925043
3afde1cbccd2ab36f90973cb985072a01ebdc64d8fdba6a895c855d90f925043
4afde1cbccd2ab36f90973cb985072a01ebdc64d8fdba6a895c855d90f925043
```

....and so on.
So as you can see these fake example hashes are listed without any details.
Now my program is suppose to calculate the hash from a selected file.

Example:
somefile.exe (or any extension)
Its 5KB in size and its SHA2 value would be:

```
3afde1cbccd2ab36f90973cb985072a01ebdc64d8fdba6a895c855d90f925043
```

Well as you can see I took the third hash from the example list right?
Now if I select `somefile.exe` for scanning then it will pass it as clean. While its blacklisted. So if I move this hash to the first position. Then my little program does correctly flag it.

So long story short I assume that something is horrible wrong with my code, even though it seems to be working.
Anyway this is what I got so far:

```
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Security
    Imports System.Security.Cryptography
    Imports MetroFramework.Forms

    Public Class Fsmain
        Function SHA256_SIG(ByVal file_name As String)
            Return SHA256_engine("SHA-256", file_name)
        End Function

        Function SHA256_engine(ByRef hash_type As String, ByRef file_name As String)

            Dim SIG
            SIG = SHA256.Create()
            Dim hashValue() As Byte

            Dim filestream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(file_name)
            filestream.Position = 0
            hashValue = SIG.ComputeHash(filestream)
            Dim hash_hex = PrintByteArray(hashValue)

            Stream.Null.Close()

            Return hash_hex
        End Function

    Public Function PrintByteArray(ByRef array() As Byte)

        Dim hex_value As String = ""
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To array.Length - 1
            hex_value += array(i).ToString("x2")
        Next i

        Return hex_value.ToLower
    End Function

    Private Sub Browsebutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Browsebutton.Click
        If SampleFetch.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim path As String = SampleFetch.FileName
            Selectfile.Text = path

            Dim Sample As String
            Sample = SHA256_SIG(path)
            SignatureREF.Text = SHA256_SIG(path)

            Using f As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("blacklist.txt")
                Using s As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(f)
                    While Not s.EndOfStream

                        Dim line As String = s.ReadLine()


                        If (line = Sample) Then
                            Result.Visible = True
                            SignatureREF.Visible = True
                            Result.Text = "Dirty"
                            Resetme.Visible = True
                            RemoveMAL.Visible = True

                        Else

                            Result.Visible = True
                            SignatureREF.Visible = True
                            Result.Text = "Clean"
                            Resetme.Visible = True
                            RemoveMAL.Visible = False

                        End If
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Fsmain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Result.Visible = False
        SignatureREF.Visible = False
        Resetme.Visible = False
        RemoveMAL.Visible = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub Resetme_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Resetme.Click

        Selectfile.Text = Nothing
        SignatureREF.Text = Nothing
        Result.Visible = False
        SignatureREF.Visible = False
        Resetme.Visible = False
        RemoveMAL.Visible = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub RemoveMAL_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RemoveMAL.Click

        Dim ask As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Would you like to remove the Dirty file?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.None)

        If ask = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(Selectfile.Text$)

        Else

            MsgBox("You sure you want to keep this file?")
            Dim filepath As String = IO.Path.Combine("c:\Dirty\", "Dirty.txt")
            Using sw As New StreamWriter(filepath)
                sw.WriteLine(" " & DateTime.Now)
                sw.WriteLine(" " & Selectfile.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(" " & SignatureREF.Text)
                sw.WriteLine(" " & Result.Text)
                sw.WriteLine("-------------------")
                sw.Close()

            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

So if any of you guys can have a look at it and point out errors, or even can come up with a fix that would be great.

Comment: Turn `Option Strict ON`, `Option Explicit ON`, `Option Infer OFF`. Revise your code after you have fixed the list of errors that come to life. Your Functions don't return a value. `Function SHA256_engine(ByRef ...)`, change `ByRef` in `ByVal`. Reading your source file, you just need a `StreamReader`, then `While [StreamReader].Peek() > 0  [StreamReader].ReadLine() (...) End While`

Comment: The body of the While-loop is wrong.  You need a variable, Dim Dirty As Boolean.  The body should be: If line = Sample Then Dirty = True.  *After* the while-loop you then use it to set the rest of the stuff.

Comment: Thx Jimi. Question when i add your code to the project it turns my whole  code in one big red error line. Now given the fact that making this program is almost like higher science to me (i am a beginner). Would you please be so kind to show me exactly how to do it? Anyway thank you for your  help.

Comment: Hi @Hans Passant, What you mean exactly? Maybe i am getting this wrong but i think i do not understand. (As i said i am a beginner) Anyway thank you for your reply.

Comment: I can't show you how to do it right now. This would imply rewriting the entire body of your class. You have to do this. There's intrinsic valuable knowledge in the re-design process. Search SO, post other specific questions. What *Hans Passant* told you will become obvious while rewriting your code. You have to test the "dirty" state of a condition, exit the loop, take action. What *jmcilhinney* showed you is another way of reading and testing the file content, in a single pass. You have to learn that too. Search for "LINQ", "method-based query", "Lambda expressions".

Comment: Hello @Jimi First of all thanks again for the reply.

Comment: @Jimi I understand what you are saying, and yes you are right. Yet i did not realize that it would require a rewrite of the code as i was under the impression that i might have made a error somewhere in the code that did not got flagged earlier and as such i was thinking that the reason for not reading the rest of the lines would be a small issue. That being said. Given the fact the code does scan the first line of the dirty list (which does work) is there a way to simplify and sort of patch up the error without having to rewrite the whole code?

Comment: Because i am more then willing to actually rewrite the code and take my lessons from it, but it would be nice to get the current code patched up so it works. So i can use that more or less as a baseline to base future versions on. Given the fact that my VBNET knowledge is limited it would require a lot of reading up and self educating before i properly can rewrite the code. So other then the adivse you already have given and that of others are there any other pointers you can give me that will help me along the way? Again thx so much for your time and help.

Comment: I understand. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you can do to make your procedure working, is testing whether a defined condition is verified. Terminate the test if that condition is met.

Using a boolean variable, report the result of the test and take action accordingly.

The `Using` statement takes care of disposing the `StreamReader`.

You could modify you procedure this way:

```
Private Sub Browsebutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Browsebutton.Click
    If SampleFetch.ShowDialog <> DialogResult.OK Then Exit Sub

    Dim sample As String = SHA256_SIG(SampleFetch.FileName)
    SignatureREF.Text = sample

    Dim isDirty As Boolean = False
    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("blacklist.txt", True)
        Dim line As String = String.Empty
        While reader.Peek() > 0
            line = reader.ReadLine()
            If line = sample Then
                isDirty = True
                Exit While
            End If
        End While
    End Using

    If isDirty Then
        '(...)
        RemoveMAL.Visible = True
        Result.Text = "Dirty"
    Else
        '(...)
        RemoveMAL.Visible = False
        Result.Text = "Clean"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Again thank you so much for the time and effort to explain me how to do it. Tomorrow i will start to work on the program and take it from there. Again thx

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `String` and you want to test whether it matches a line of a text file then you can use this simple one-liner:

```
If IO.File.ReadLines(filePath).Contains(myString) Then
```

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney thx for the reply. I copied your line and saved it to a notepath++ file i am currently trying to fit in what Jimi suggested. Anyway where would i put this into my script?

Comment: There is no script. VB.NET is not a scripting language. You would put that line of code into your code wherever you need what that line does doing. That line tests whether a `String` matches any line in a file. Where do you need that doing? That's where you put that line of code.